# subset a DNAStringSet by subpattern and remove subpattern in R

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics, fasta, bioconductor

I want to subset only the lines that contain the substring and then to remove the substring. I can do the first part, but I do not know how to remove the substring

Here is an example

```
library(Biostrings)
myseq <-DNAStringSet(c("CCCATGAAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACCCATGAA", "CCCATGAACATAGATCC", "CCCGTACAGATCACGTG"))
names(myseq) <- letters[1:3]
myseq

A DNAStringSet instance of length 3
width seq                                                                                                           names               
[1]    40 CCCATGAAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACCCATGAA                                                                    a
[2]    17 CCCATGAACATAGATCC                                                                                           b
[3]    17 CCCGTACAGATCACGTG                                                                                           c
```

The sequence I want to remove is *AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA* which is in the first line.

```
matchPattern("AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA", myseq[[1]])

Views on a 40-letter DNAString subject
subject: CCCATGAAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACCCATGAA
views:
    start end width
[1]     9  32    24 [AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA]
```

to subset I do the following:

```
pat <- vmatchPattern("AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA", myseq)
myseq[ lapply(lapply(pat, isEmpty), function(x) x == FALSE) ]

A DNAStringSet instance of length 3
    width seq                                                                                                         names               
[1]    40 CCCATGAAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACCCATGAA                                                                    a
[2]     0                                                                                                             b
[3]     0                                                                                                             c
```

The output should be

```
A DNAStringSet instance of length 3
    width seq                                                                                                         names               
[1]    11 CCCCCCATGAA                                                                                                 a
[2]     0                                                                                                             b
[3]     0                                                                                                             c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `vcountPattern` to count matches within an `ifelse` statement, replacing matches with the output of `str_replace` and non-matches with empty strings:

```
myseq2 <- DNAStringSet(
            unlist(
              lapply(
                vcountPattern(
                 'AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA', myseq) > 0, 
                  ifelse, 
                  str_replace(
                    myseq, 
                   'AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA', 
                   ''),
                '')
              )
            )
names(myseq2) <- names(myseq)
myseq2

>A DNAStringSet instance of length 3
>width seq                                                     names               
>[1]    16 CCCATGAACCCATGAA                                        a
>[2]     0                                                         b
>[3]     0                                                         c
```

Slightly more readable with pipe notation:

```
lapply(vcountPattern('AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA', myseq) > 0, ifelse, str_replace(myseq, 'AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA', ''), '') %>%
    unlist() %>%
    DNAStringSet() -> myseq2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the bioinformatics package, but if you are ok with converting the data to list (I am confident it should be possible to convert list to the format used in the package), the following approach can be used:

1) use stringr library to remove the desired pattern
2) calculate the length of the new pattern

```
# load biostrings package
library(Biostrings)

# create sample dataset
myseq <-DNAStringSet(c("CCCATGAAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACCCATGAA", "CCCATGAACATAGATCC", "CCCGTACAGATCACGTG"))
names(myseq) <- letters[1:3]

# remove sequences with no match
pat <- vmatchPattern("AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA", myseq)
data <- myseq[ lapply(lapply(pat, isEmpty), function(x) x == FALSE) ]

# load stringr library
library(stringr)

# replace the matched sequence
test <- lapply(test, str_replace, "AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAA", "")
# put together the new sequence and its length
test <- mapply(c, lapply(test, nchar), test, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```